# Angular - multiselect-dropdown - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```js
  counter: number = 0;
  getDatatypes(){
    if(this.counter == 0) {
      if(this.appId != 0)
      {
        if(undefined != this.datatypes && this.datatypes.length)
          for (let i = 0; i < this.datatypes.length; i++) {
            this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, this.datatypes[i].dataTypeId, this.datatypes[i].description, false);
            let datatype = this.checkedDatatypes.find(y => y.description === this.datatypes[i].description);
            if (datatype) {
              this.applicationDataType.checked = true;
              this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
            } else {
              this.applicationDataType.checked = false;
              this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
            }
        }
      } else {
        for(let i = 0; i < this.datatypes.length; i++){
          this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, this.datatypes[i].dataTypeId, this.datatypes[i].description, false);
          this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
        }
      }
      this.counter ++;
    }
  }
```

The line

```js
if(undefined != this.datatypes && this.datatypes.length)
```

is the one giving the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

This is the console error I am getting

[image]

These errors are not visible to the user and do not affect the functionality. I have tried everything, but the datatypes in the front end multi select-dropdown just keep disappearing. I have tried initializing datatypes: Datatype[] = [], wrapping my for loop with `if(this.datatypes && this.datatypes.length)`, and using ?. These just make the multi select-dropdown empty when running the front end.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like `this.datatypes` is not an array or its null ,you can simply ignore this error with `?` .

Please Change this to `if(this.datatypes?.length>0)`

Comment: I tried that, but it made the multi-select dropdown list disappear.

Comment: The safety operator is from typescript 3.7, I think that Angular use typescript 3.1. gererally I use `if (this.datatypes && this.datatypes.length)`. This include is this.datatypes is null

Comment: @Eliseo I have also tried wrapping my for loop with that, but it made the dropdown empty.

Comment: has you forget a `{` in the if(undefined != this.datatypes....) when you write the question?

Comment: No, I didn’t @Eliseo

Comment: @Eliseo alright, so I’m looping through objects, and objects don’t have length. How do I fix my code according to this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try as below. initialize dataTypes array, then replace for loop with forEach as below

```
counter: number = 0;
  datatypes = [];
  getDatatypes(){
    if(this.counter == 0) {
      if(this.appId != 0)
      {
        this.datatypes.forEach(dtype => {
          this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, dtype.dataTypeId, dtype.description, false);
            let datatype = this.checkedDatatypes.find(y => y.description === dtype.description);
            if (datatype) {
              this.applicationDataType.checked = true;
              this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
            } else {
              this.applicationDataType.checked = false;
              this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
            }
        })
      } else {
        this.datatypes.forEach(dtype => {
          this.applicationDataType = new ApplicationDataType(this.route.snapshot.params.id, dtype.dataTypeId, dtype.description, false);
          this.applicationDataTypes.push(this.applicationDataType);
        })
      }
      this.counter ++;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I initialized the datatypes. `export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  appId: number;
  dataTypeId: number;
  application: Application;
  appData: AppData;
  appDatas: AppData[];
  datatypes: Datatype[];` I tried the code you gave me, but I deleted your `datatypes = [];`, because it was giving me error since it is under export class, but it gave me `core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: I am getting `core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: What error datatypes: Datatype[] was giving when you declared it inside the class ? datatypes has to be declared and initialized to use it. was it already declared ?

Comment: if possible can you show the code of where the datatypes in declared and where its value is assigned? thanks

Comment: as a temp fix i would propose to replace "this.datatypes.forEach" with "this.datatypes && this.datatypes.forEach" as of now. But we need to find how and where the datatypes is declared and fix it there.

Comment: `export class ApplicationComponent implements OnInit {

  username: string;
  appId: number;
  dataTypeId: number;
  application: Application;
  appData: AppData;
  appDatas: AppData[];
  datatypes: Datatype[];
  checkedDatatypes: Datatype[];
  hide = true;
  exists = false;
  appDataId;
  applicationDataType: ApplicationDataType;
  applicationDataTypes: ApplicationDataType[];
  newApplication: number;` That is the class where I declared it. I also tried replacing `this.datatypes.forEach` but it made the dropdown list disappear again.

Comment: ok, the problem is this.datatypes is not assigned with value properly. as per your above comment you have declared datatypes variable but it is not defined with any value.

Comment: I fixed that with datatypes: Datatype[] = [], but it still made the drop down menu items disappear.

Comment: I think I know the problem. I’m looping through objects, and objects don’t have length. How do I fix my code according to this?

Comment: Im getting bit confused here. In your code you have declared it as array "datatypes: Datatype[]" ? May I know what is the value of this.datatypes is ?

Comment: this is array of objects